# Как манипулировать динамическими элементами?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Всем доброго дня!
Есть`<input type="hidden" id="currency">`
Ajax-ом я в value записываю данные, но в дальнейшем когда обращаюсь к нему выдает изначальное пустое значение

```
var currency = $('#currency').val();  // currency пустой
```

Как присвоить значение переменной, которая динамично была присвоена в input?
Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: лучше бы Вы показали, как добавляете значения

Comment: Пробовали через .attr('value')?

Comment: `$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'get_currency',
            // data: 'id=' + mark_data_value,
            success: function(data){
              $('#currency').val(data);
            }
         })`

Comment: А вот сразу после этой строчки сделайте `console.log($('#currency').val());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#currency').val('some_data');
```

если не помогает, то в дебаггере убедиться что:

- в момент установки значения элемент с id="currency" существует;
- такой элемент только один.

Comment: Дополню ответ - возможно ваш код выполняется до того, как становиться доступ input c id 'currency'. Из-за этого не находится элемент и естественно, никуда не ложится значения, полученные с сервера.